# Omit footer and centralise Motion Chart created with googleVis R package

Tags: r, motion

It's a general question, not one related to any specific chart; hence I'm not adding any code. 
It seems there isn't a "footer" option you can use to control how the motion chart appears, in a similar vein as there are options to control for width, colours, omit the right-hand menus, etc.
Also, how can I present the chart centralised on the page rather than starting from the top left-hand corner?
Regards,
José

Answer (score 0):

Trend Compass is a new concept in viewing statistics and trends in an animated way by displaying in one chart 5 axis (X, Y, Time, Bubble size & Bubble color) instead of just the traditional X and Y axis. It could be used in analysis, research, presentation etc.

Link on UK Master Card vs Visa performance:
http://www.epicsyst.com/test/v2/mastercard_vs_visa/

Link showing Drilling feature (Parent/Child) - Just double-click on any bubble:
http://www.epicsyst.com/test/v2/drilling/